# Determine reducibility of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Determine whether the polynomial $ x^3-9 $ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}_{31}$, and over $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$.

Since $ x^3-9 $ is of degree $\leq 3$, it is reducible over a field $F$ if it has a root in $F$.
So one possible way is to check if there is a root in $F$ by checking all possible values.
Are there other possible ways?

Comment: For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).

Answer (score 3):

Consider whether $x^3-9$ has a root in $\mathbb Z_p$, for a prime $p$.

The multiplicative group of $\mathbb Z_p$ has order $p-1$.
When $(3,p-1)=1$, we have that the homomorphism $x\mapsto x^3$ is injective and hence bijective. This means that every element is a cube.

Since $(3,10)=1$, we know that $x^3-9$ has a root in $\mathbb Z_{11}$, even if you don't know it. (It's $4$.)

I don't know an argument for $p=31$, though.

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_reciprocity.

Answer (score 2):

Take a primitive root ad obtain a linear congruence.
For example, 3 is a primitive root mod 31, thus the congruence $ x^3=9\pmod {31} $ become $3y=2\pmod {30} $ which clearly has no solutions.